# Why isn't my CSS style changing the attribute height here?

Tags: html, css

If I set width of the "div" element to % it works fine, but if I set the height to a % I get nothing. Only if I specify the height in px or em or something does it work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
    <style>
        div {
            background-color: aqua;
            height: 25%;
            width: 25%;
             float: left; 
            }
    </style>

<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is confusing me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
    body{
       height: 100vh;
       width: 100vw;
    }
    div {
        background-color: aqua;
        height: 25%;
        width: 25%;
         float: left; 
        }
</style>
```

When you set `width` or `height` with %, You have to check it's parent tag.

For example,

```
.parent{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 }

.children{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

`.children` 's `height` and `width` is `100px`.

Let's see another exmaple.

```
.parent{

}
.children{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

`.children`'s `height` and `width` is `0px`.

because it's parent doesn't have `width` and `height`.

Comment: Thank you.  I was just wondering what specifying the body as 100vh actually does, specifically why it makes div height accept a percentage.

Comment: vh is a css unit that *always* refers to the percentage of the screen height. vw is the same thing for width. Using 100% can refer to different things. If a parent has a relative position and a child element has relative position, 100% for the child element will refer to 100% of its parent's width/height. Not the screen width. And percentages won't work if the parent element doesn't have some determinable width or height. The screen always has a determinable width height, so it works.

Answer (score 2):

the dive will get 25% of its parent height and width so if you didn't style body to have an special height or width it most be 0px in you'r case add some height to body and it will get styled

```
body {
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
```